# Why the object is moving the opposite direction when decreasing the movement speed value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
float distance1 = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);
if(distance1 < 10)
{
    movementSpeed -= 0.01f;
}
                    
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
```

If for example I did it this way it will increase the movement speed slowly :

```
movementSpeed += Time.deltaTime * 0.01f;
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destinationTransform.position, Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
```

but i want the object to slowly decrease the movement speed down when getting close to the target.

when i'm changing it to -= the object is moving backward.

Comment: When is it close enough? What if the distance1 is too far before movementSpeed will go below 0? Because the movementSpeed will be negative at some point. (it stops and then increases negative speed)